# Linking CiviCase with a CiviEvent

Tags: civievent, civicase

This one may have an obvious answer, but I just cant seem to find a simple solution. 
Running Wordpress 4.2.2 CiviCRM 4.6.3

In a nutshell We want to use CiviCase to coordinate Event management. The Events will be using CiviEvent to deal with venue and participant sign ups etc.

So the Case will be auto assigned to an Event Manager (case coordinator), and also their boss (case supervisor), the Event Manager will go through the steps of the case, such as getting quotes for venue, then tick off from supervisor, then A/V system etc, then any talent issues, then setting up promo etc etc.

So What i want to do is work out a simple way to connect the Case to the particular CiviEvent that will already have been created - so you can easily say click through to the Event from the case..

An obvious way would be to Make the CiviEvent the equivalent of the client, meaning the Case coordinator, and supervisor end up with a role / relationship with the target which is a CiviEvent instead of an individual client - but the case set up does not quite work like that, and it seems case relationships cant be with Events only contact types.

At the most basic it could just be a link in custom field I guess?

But this leaves the problem - who or what should be the client when setting up a new case? Perhaps a dummy Contact could fill this role..

As I said maybe I am just missing a simple solution here, any help appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who are you organising the event for? Your organisation seems to be the most natural, but having a client of a case (used to be?) is tricky. If it doesn't work easily with your org, I'd put the event manager as the "client".

As for creating the link, I'd put a custom field (integer) that contains the id of the related entity. I'm not sure I'd put the event id on the case or the case id on the event, depends of your workflow and which one is created first, and a tiny extension to display the id as a link instead of the number.

X+

Comment: Thanks Xavier - interesting ideas. particularly the use of an Event Manager as the client. I'm gonna test that approach out and see where it leaves me with reporting etc to see if it works.. 
- If this works i will mark your comments as the answer

And your event id idea is definitely the way forward.. a little extension adding the rest of the html for a URL will work a treat - I just need to decide exactly which URL I want them to head to - probably the Event registered participants page.. I

Comment: Hi Xavier - we are going with a slight variation on your idea -  we will Use the Event Supervisor (civi = case supervisor) as the Client. This means that this role is attached to the case at the first instance, which ensures the coordinator is less like to forget linking them. It also means our civi -reporting on these cases is less complex - the manager and supervisor can just take variations on the same report template.. And the link Idea will be a winner, so marking this as answered..